# Copying and pasting files within .jar

Tags: bash, file, jar, zip

I am writing a script that will copy a bunch of files from a .jar file and I want to paste it into another .jar file.

This is a bash script.

How can I do this without having to extract and repack both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by command line. Here is a better explanation about how it works:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Answer (score 0):

from this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html
use this command to extract files:

`jar xf jar-file archived-file(s)`

then you can update a jar file http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html using this command:

`jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`